# How to build a WCF service that consumes data given an XSD

Tags: wcf

I have been provided an XSD and a sample Xml file that contains the results I will be getting.
I am to build a Web Service that accepts this data and enter into a SQL 2005 table. Each time my service is invoked, I am expecting 1200+ rows of data.

I have also been provided two Xml files, success.xml and failure.xml, that are responses I am to provide back to the caller?

I would like to build a WCF service on the .Net 4.0 framework with one 'MethodToCall'. The other party would call this web service and pass in the data.

I used the SVCUTIL.exe file.xsd /dconly /importxmltypes to get an output.cs file.

Now what do I do?

How do I iterate through the rows to add to my table?
With so many rows, will I run into issues of having my service timeout or something?
Can I do the table insert/update in a batch after disconnecting from the wire?

Any sample or pseudo code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I iterate through the rows to add to my table?

usually it generates classes using List for sequences in XSD, so you can iterate using foreach.

> With so many rows, will I run into issues of having my service timeout
>   or something?
>
> There are settings of binding like

```
<readerQuotas
maxDepth="" 
maxStringContentLength="" 
maxArrayLength="" 
maxBytesPerRead="" 
maxNameTableCharCount="" />
```

consider to increase its values.

> Can I do the table insert/update in a batch after disconnecting from
>   the wire?

Think again, do you really need it? You should send response to sender that data is successfully processed. But you are going to send the response before data is written to the database. It could cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

if the xml you got is not a soap envelope than you cannot build a wcf service that gets exactly it. you can build a service that gets that xml wrapped inside soap. that may or may not be what you want. to build a service that gets exaclty this xml use [asp.net web api](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/02/23/asp-net-web-api-part-1.aspx).

to build a wcf service given an xsd (and considering the limitation above) use [wscf.blue](http://wscfblue.codeplex.com/).